# PC crashes, monitor shuts off, Numlock stuck, when playing any 3D game

Tags: crash, amd-graphics-card

When I play any 3D games, I run it and within just 1-3 seconds, the monitors shuts off, <kbd>Numlock</kbd> stuck, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is useless, no bluescreen, no kernel dump, HD light is dark. The only thing I can do is reboot.

1. Windows 7, Intel E3 1230, RAM 8 GB, AMD RX 470.
2. Everything is ok, except 3D games. Playing 2D games and movies is fine. 3D test software and BlueStacks also crashes it.
3. The temperature of the graphics card is normal, below 53 °C.
4. I have tried to uninstall use DDU, and reinstall the newest driver.
5. I have already cleaned the dust of the PC.
6. I change and reset the WattMan in the AMD settings but it's useless.
7. Try to play a music, a movie, and a set timer progress, then play a 3d game, less than 3 second, monitor shuts off, 1-3 second, the  sound become wowowowo. So it is system crash, not only graphic card.
8. Set kernel dump, but the fold of dump is empty.
9. System log didn't log the event of crash , only log reboot.
10. No warning in the device manager.

Everything was working fine for the past 6 years and this problem only appeared today.

Comment: Are you on latest chipset drive? Are you able to borrow another gpu

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The chipset driver is latest,the company stop update driver a long time ago. I  have no other GPU to change. Before today , all thing is fine. I use it at least 6 years. The crash comes suddently, now i couldn't in any 3D game and software.

Comment: Is your BIOS up to date? Without spare hardware for swapping this will be rather hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: The Bios  stop update too. I use this motherboard 6 years, and the graphics card more than 2 years.  In this time, It work fine and i am not update both Bios. Today i didn't change any hardware and software, but it couldn't run 3d.